# Using the WordPress TinyMCE in an HTML iframe for plugin

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have a WordPress plugin with settings page. On this settings page, the form to be submitted is loaded in an iframe. I wish to utilize the WordPress TinyMCE for a textarea in this form.

How do I achieve this? I can't really do it the way it is stated here (http://keighl.com/post/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/) since the form is present in an HTML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WORDPRESS 3.5 UPDATE BELOW**

If you're using Wordpress version<3.0, you can use the post you referenced to, it's great.

If your wordpress version is above 3.0 (aka newer versions) you can't use the `wp_tiny_mce` function for the tiny_mce, because it's deprecated. You need the newer function, `wp_editor`, which you can read all about it in here:

> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

For you to use of the `wp_editor` function and other WP elements your iframe (the for now containing only html and not linked into wp), you need to make your the **iframe html file** a **php file**, and add a require function of **wp-load.php** file.

For example, if your iframe file is in your server's root folder with your wordpress install, all you need to do is to place the following in the top of your file:

```
<?php 
require('./wp-load.php'); 
?>

//iframe html/php code here
```

After you do that you can use any wordpress function in your iframe, including the tiny_mce.

**---- UPDATE ----**

If you are using wordpress 3.5 or higher, the implement method has slightly changed. more information is right in this short [tutorial](http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/)

Comment: That's not the only required code. Still missing the styles and scripts for the RTE to function. Can you post the entire code? Thanks

Comment: what version of wordpress are you using, and where in the system are you trying to implement the editor? also, look here if you are using wordpress>=3.5 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847714/wordpress-3-5-custom-media-upload-for-your-theme-options