# Wordpress and WP MVC upload images

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need a way to add images/gallery to a model created by the [WP MVC](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mvc/) plugin(which is pretty awesome) for wordpress. It would be nice to tie in the new functionality offered in 3.5 but I really don't know where to start with this.

I tried a few google searches but I could not find anything pertaining to my needs.

Thank you for any assistance.

[image: Custom Model Lawyers]

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847714/wordpress-3-5-custom-media-upload-for-your-theme-options

Comment: This looks promising thanks.

Comment: I keep getting @wpActiveEditor is not defined@. I think this is related to tinyMCE?

Comment: adding wp_editor fixes this but I would rather not load the wp_editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it's something to help

https://gist.github.com/4283059

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75808/using-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-meta-box

Comment: Your link in the comments section helped me the most. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I also got the error "wpActiveEditor is not defined" while trying to use media dialog on my custom page. As I saw, script tries to use property `window.wpActiveEditor` that is not defined. So the solution is to define the property

```
window.wpActiveEditor = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens when you do the following:

```
$(selector).click(function(){
    // ...
    // initialization code
    // ...
    exports.media.editor.open();
});
```

If you pass $(this) as a first parameter to this open(), the problem will be solved:

```
$(selector).click(function(){
    // ...
    // initialization code
    // ...
    exports.media.editor.open($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP function wp_handle_upload
something like this in your GalleriesController

```
function upload(){
    if(!empty($this->params['data'])){
        $overrides = array('test_form' => false);
        $file = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['file'],$overrides );
        $this->params['data']['Photo']['file'] = $file['url'];
        $this->params['data']['Photo']['title'] = basename ($file['file']);
        $this->Photo->save($this->params['data']);
    }
}
```