# WordPress: 3.5+ Attach Gallery To Post and Use Template Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, media, wordpress-3.5

Just wonder if WordPress 3.5+ still attach gallery even if it is not added to the post content area.

Earlier WordPress was adding gallery as an attachment and allowing to populate via template tag even if it is not added to the content area. Now with version 3.5.1 I am trying to create a gallery and it is displaying if I add to the post content but as soon as I remove from the post content than gallery just disappear from the media library as well and there is no attachment found for the post.

Just wonder and trying to understand how they have changed the media library and gallery. I understand the basic that before they were creating a gallery id but now they are adding only image id so there is no more gallery id. Is that correct?

So question how can I add gallery using template tag something like `<?php echo do_shortocode('[gallery link="file"]'); ?>` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost answered this question yourself!

[Check the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) for the specifics.

I needed to do this with with a custom meta box and the details can be found here. [Pre-Select Images when opening WordPress 3.5 media manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936080/pre-select-images-when-opening-wordpress-3-5-media-manager).

EDIT:

For the benefit of other readers and for clarification, something like this is required

```
echo do_shortcode( '[gallery ids="139,138,137,136"]' );
```

Where the ids is a comma seperated list of attachment id's you want included. This is it in the simplest form - check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) for more options.

Comment: I have already tried that but its not display any gallery since worpress changed system in 3.5 its removeing gallery if not inserted to post content. Now I dont know what I should and how.

Comment: It does work :) your spelling in the OP is incorrect. Make sure you're typing something like this 
echo do_shortcode( '[gallery ids="139,138,137,136"]' ); 
Where the numbers are swapped with the image ids you want.

Comment: I have tried this `echo do_shortcode('[gallery link="file"]');` and not adding any gallery.

Comment: Oh I see. I missunderstood entire concept. Where it now allows you to create gallery with already uploaded image (unlinke before ) I thought that will work too and so I didn't realized that only attached item will be considered as a gallery to display with shortcode. Thanks working now